# Why are two objects referenced in this variable assignment?

Tags: javascript

In node module.js file there is this line of code:

```
exports = module.exports = {
   makeRequireFunction,
   stripBOM,
   addBuiltinLibsToObject
};
```

What is this doing?

```
 exports = module.exports
```

Ultimately, exports is being set to this new object:

```
= {
   makeRequireFunction,
   stripBOM,
   addBuiltinLibsToObject
};
```

Why is exports = module.exports needed?

Comment: If this works like it does in Python, it is simply assigning the same value to  two variables (`exports` and `module.exports`) in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a shortcut to allow you to continue to use `exports.[whatever]` further down in the file. Ultimately, it's the contents of `module.exports` that gets "exported".